# How to implement a publish/subscribe in java using also callbacks. Do I have to use JMS?

Tags: java, jms, publish

I need to obtain info from a web and use it in my application. I have to make a server and a client that gets info from my server. Server has to retrieve info from the web.
If I have to use JMS, have any of you any example project?

Comment: Why would you have to use JMS? In other words, you thinking that you might need to leads me to believe you're leaving out information.

Comment: Agree with @DaveNewton, according to wikipedia "It [JMS] is a messaging standard that allows application components based on the Java Enterprise Edition (JEE) to create, send, receive, and read messages." From your description I doubt you need to create a full JavaEE compliant application. You probably want to research Web Services and how to implement them using Java. If you could give us more information on the requirements, we might be of better service to you.